# Complexity for Recursive Function (Big O Notation)

Tags: c++, recursion, big-o, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I know how to find the complexity of a basic recursive function such as a factorial function, but I don't know how to get started on how to do something a little more complicated like this. What would the time complexity notation be for mystery(n)? I would appreciate any help because I'm trying to practice for a midterm, thank you.

```
    int mystery(int n )
    {
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
            res += 1;
        }

        if (n <= 0){
            return res;
        } else {
            return res + mystery(n - 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking the complexity of `mystery`?

Comment: Which is the complexity of `mystery(0)` ? which is the complexity of `mystery(n)` knowing complexity of `mystery(n - 1)` ?

Comment: Time `O(n^2)`  space `O(n)`

Comment: Btw, the loop can be replaced with `const int res = (n + 1) / 2;`.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, I meant to ask " what is the time complexity of mystery(n) , basically the time it takes to calculate mystery(n) in terms of asymptotic analysis"?

Comment: What makes this function too complex to analyse with methods you do know?

Comment: @n.m. I'm not sure how the for loop in the mystery function affects the time complexity of mystery(n). I only really know how to do recursive functions like factorial(n), because there isn't anything else going on in the function except for checking if n == 0.

Comment: You need to add the time it takes to run the loop (at each recursive call) to the total time.

Comment: @n.m. Would the time it takes to run the loop at each recursive call be (n/2) then, since it's increasing by 2 in each loop? If it's n/2, then the time complexity comes from (n/2) * (n-1), where (n-1) is the recursive call to mystery. So, it's O(n^2)? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Note n is changing at each recursive call, so the total time in the loop is (n/2 +(n-1)/2+...) which is about n^2/4. It's still O(n^2) in this case but in general you have to be very careful.